Washing Yeast. How much is good yeast?
I finished a 10gal batch of ESB last weekend and I am trying to wash the yeast to keep it for next time. I am not seeing a clear separation in layers though. Can anyone tell me how much of this is good yeast?


All three look like good yeast to me! I don't usually see a stratification in the yeast but also don't wash my yeast so may be why. The times I have noticed it was after the yeast sat in the keezer for a month or so. One thing you may want to think about -- if you store the jars this way though, you may want to fill them up with a little more beer next time to keep as much oxygen out of the jar as you can.

Thanks for the help! I actually filled them with boiled and cooled water which is supposed to be to get the separation? I have always read that's what to do. Will this yeast be okay after a month?

You bet! I'm not sure about the boiled and cooled water for separation. I spent a couple days messing around trying to get that "prime" layer and just gave up. This is one of several disucssions on the topic (https://forum.homebrewersassociation.org/t/yeast-washing/25163/1). "Denny" on that thread has been doing this for 20 years or so.  Knows his stuff. Lots of good info in the archives. Generally a month is fine but keep it chilled and give it a whiff a few days before your next brew. If it smells oxidized, cheesy or funky, I'd dump it. And, make a starter if you can, it's cheap insurance

For sure, I always make a starter! Thanks for your help!

Oh another question. So it looks like they are saying just take ALL the trub and put it in the fridge with some beer on top? That would be almost a gallon of trub/yeast from my last batch. How do I make a starter from that without it going crazy and over flowing the bottle? Put it in 2 separate gallons? Or maybe just use a tiny bit of DME for the starter?

Sort of, but not everything in one container. I'll gently swirl trub leftovers around to get it all mixed together again (introduce as little oxygen as possible). sanitize three 16oz mason jars and "Leak Proof Storage Lids" (the metal ones corrode). Divide trub into the 3 jars about 1/4" from top. Chill. For the starter, boil 4 cups distilled water in microwave with 1/4 cup of DME + some yeast nutrient (10 mins). Let it chill to room temp. sanitize a clean 1 gallon cider jug. dump in "wort", trub. shake like a mofo to aerate yeast. Wrap foil around the top or loose lid. Shake every so often.

PS: before using the re-pitch, give it a whiff out of the fridge. It shouldn't smell "bad", but just "yeasty and beery". If it smells like oxidized beer, or cheesy, or just something off, don't bother with it. Something got goofed up. Also, give the starter a whiff every so often too. If it doesn't smell right, dump it. I've only had this happen a couple of times so it's not terribly often.

PPS: the DME and water solution (wort) for the start is a contested recipe. Some use more DME, some less. I read a document last year that said less DME was actually beneficial to the yeast but morebeer has a nice writeup here that would be a good starting point: https://www.morebeer.com/articles/Making_Yeast_Starter

Thanks so much! So I think what you are saying is just keep 3 Mason jars worth of trub? The steps you said is pretty much what I do. But I usually use 2 can starters and 1 pack of yeast in a 2L starter. So in this case can I use the trub from 3 jars + 2 starter cans? I bought stainless steel lids with seals online for the jars. Seem pretty nice.

You bet. Yeah, I just pour the slurry into 3 jars and use each one for a starter later on. I've not used the canned starters so not sure how they would work into the mix. I just boil the DME, chill, dump in a 16oz jar of slurry and let it take off. Lately. I tried some stainless lids from amazon but after a few months, they developed some corrosion so bought the plastic ones. Might have been made out of some grade that didn't like the low pH.. dunno for sure. Hopefully your experience is better. The plastic is a little risky due to scratching, etc.
